# Rcpp error: no matching function for call to 'distance(Rcpp::Vector<14, Rcpp::PreserveStorage&, Rcpp::Vector<14,Rcpp::PreserveStorage>&)'

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am new to Rcpp.  I am trying to write Rcpp code and I have this error when compile the code [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmcv6.png)

And here is the code I write , I think the other code is find just this part makes the error:

Th rcpp_node is the other function I define which gives a list including "x" and "w"

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]

double rcpp_sample_bi(NumericMatrix x1,NumericMatrix x2,NumericVector theta,NumericVector x11,NumericVector x21,NumericVector df,NumericVector d,NumericVector p,double it){
  double iter=0;
  double a=0.0;
  double b=1-a;
  while(iter<it){
    double c=(a+b)/2;
    NumericVector cc1_x=rcpp_node(a,c,3)["x"];
    NumericVector cc2_x=rcpp_node(c,b,3)["x"];
    NumericVector cc1_w=rcpp_node(a,c,3)["w"];
    NumericVector cc2_w=rcpp_node(c,b,3)["w"];
    NumericVector cc= {cc1_x,cc2_x};
    NumericVector d(6);
    for(int i;i<d.size();i++)
      d[i]=rcpp_loglike(x1,x2,theta,x11,x21,cc[i],df,d,p);
    d=exp(d-max(d))/sum(exp(d-max(d))); 
    double L=0;
    NumericVector integer = {4,5,6};
    for(int i;i<cc1_w.size();i++)
      L+=cc1_w[i]*d[i];
    double R=0;
    NumericVector f=d[integer];
    for(int i;i<cc2_w.size();i++)
      R+=cc2_w[i]*f[i];
    double prob=L/(R+L);
    double e=R::rbinom(1,prob);
    if(e==0){b=c;}
    a=c;
    iter++;
  }
  return R::runif(a,b);
}
```

I tried to search online but no one had this error before

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, and Rcpp!  It may be a good time to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) because your question cannot really get any answers as it is not a [minimally complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  We lack your other functions. Posting an image is also strongly discouraged, paste the (textual) output using formating, if possible.